# How to customize a toolbar in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way to customize toolbar in Xcode 4? Reorder buttons, remove default and add new? Also I want to turn off text under toolbar buttons, since I run Xcode 4 on 13" Macbook where every pixel is precious.

Comment: I've seen toolbar without text in XCode in WWDC2010 videos. So I believe there IS a possibility at least to change icons & text sizes. But I can't figure how! Standard right click on toolbar not working. In "View" menu there is no "Customize toolbar..." option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To turn off text underneath the buttons just cmd+click on the top right button (on the level with the traffic lights). This is a global thing.

The rest you're stuck with I'm afraid.

Comment: one of the major reasons i hate xcode with a passion there are several tools i use regularly and prefer having buttons for them readily available and not just through key bindings

Answer (score 2):

According to: http://pilky.me/view/16 toolbar customization is gone, and unlikely to return :(

Answer (score 1):

As Elibud says toolbar customisation is no longer available, I use a 13" Macbook and, minimise them. I am running Xcode V3, it's a bit easier to see all the windows as you can move all the menus around and open Interface Builder separately.